# How to create a Vampire Dark Ages 20th edition character?

Tags: character-creation, optimization, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages

I'm a novice of the World of Darkness, the lore lured me in. I've bought the Vampire Dark Ages 20th edition (last available afaik) and I'm ready to get into DM'ing !

At least that was the point.

I'm having a LOT of trouble to process even basic interactions between characters and how to *create* characters correctly. I've seen a bunch of pre-made characters in the supplement "Cathar Heresy", none of them seems equal in any way. Most notably, the Gangrel one seems to be totally unbeatable by any of the other pre-made.

I guess that should be fine anyway since they're not supposed to attack each other, but the differences in power really made me wonder what exactly I missed into character creation, but i couldn't emulate the guy.

Re-reading the rules of character creation really made me brain-fart or whatever, I couldn't be sure of anything. About the attributes, I'm kinda good, it's for everything else that I'm lost. Abilities and Disciplines are very obscure to me.

Most notably, why wouldn't I put all my available points into a single discipline? The differences between Fortitude 1 and 3 is kinda huge and that's just an example. Is there something preventing this? Will your character have trouble down the line for not having put any points into his other disciplines?

So if we had to summarize, what, as a DM, should I look the most in my character stats? If I see none of my PCs has access to say, obfuscate, and all of them have low apparences like 3, are they going to have a lot of trouble down the line ? Are some abilities "trap" in the sense that they're not really useful and tends to make suboptimal builds and thus reduce the power level of the group significantly ? Are, therefore, some bloodlines more useful for beginners PCs and/or easier to manage for beginner DMs?
What would make you say a character is optimized at creation ?

Comment: You've got at least two separate questions here. One about character creation / optimization and the other looking for a character generator. I'd recommend emphasizing whichever is most important to you.

Comment: We've closed the question waiting for it to be [edit]ed into a clearly defined singular (focused) question. Once it has been so, it will be reopened. If any of this is confusing, feel free to ask. (@ me here, or join us in [chat])

Comment: It might be more about the optimization and what i should look at especially for stats. I'm editing this

Comment: I've voted to reopen despite it technically asking a lot of questions, because I don't know the system well enough to tell how broad/disconnected they are. If anyone with system expertise would like to state/clarify otherwise that would be appreciated.

Comment: How many members does your party have, what are you planning to run, what do your players want to play?

Comment: @Akixkisu i've got 3 regulars and one taggalong. I'm wishing to try a chronicle, they come from playing d&d and want a more "mature" game.

Comment: @LamaDelRay what do you mean by mature?

Comment: @Akixkisu It's not my will but i think it's the "darkest" mood and the fact it's much more character based, less a "open door, kill monster, loot treasure" and different from d&d in scope

Comment: @Akixkisu or maybe they just dig the "be vampires!" part, they just expressed it was cool and wanted to try it so